# Swift: Launching a Camera from custom cell

Tags: swift, ios8

I have a custom Cell with a button inside.  When that button is tap, I would like to launch the Camera.

Custom Cell Xib:

[image]

//Custom Button Cell Class
Code:

```
import UIKit

class CameraCell: UITableViewCell, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var buttonCamera: UIButton!

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
    }

    override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

    @IBAction func buttonCameraTapped(sender: UIButton) {

    if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera) {

    let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()

    imagePicker.delegate = self
    imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera
    imagePicker.mediaTypes = [kUTTypeImage]
    imagePicker.allowsEditing = false

    self.presentViewController(imagePicker, animated: true,
    completion: nil)
    //This 'CameraCell' does not have a member named 'presentViewController'
        }
    }
```

Error: `This 'CameraCell' does not have a member named 'presentViewController'`

I will also need a delegate (UIImagePickerControllerDelegate) to handle the events after the pictures are taken.

How do I launch the camera from a button inside a custom cell and set it up as Camera Delegate?

Answer (score 2):

Because you are in the subclass of `UITableViewCell`, how can you call `presentViewController`. Only `UIViewController` can call it.

What I would do is to handle the trigger of `UIImageViewController` in the `UIViewController` that you handle the cells.

Comment: How do I keep track if the button inside a custom cell was pressed in UITableViewController?

Comment: Where do you distribute the data to your cell? That's the place where you should present the `UIImageViewController`